# How to pass dynamic data types as parameters in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, methods, parameters

I have a method in c# which builds xml on the fly.

However, I won't know the specific elements/attributes until run-time.

How do I declare parameters when I don't know what the data-types, names and values or amount will be?

Comment: Doesn't sound like you know what you want to do.  Can you add some examples?

Comment: Are you reinventing [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx)?

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for [params](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) keyword. Or are you? :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `System.Object` for all parameters, since it is the base class for all other types. You can then find out the actual declared type with the `GetType()` method, and treat the value appropriately.

e.g.

```
if (myParam.GetType() == typeof(Int32)) 
{
   // treat value as integer ...
   int val = (int)myParam;
}
```

or you can use the syntax

```
if (myParam is Int32)
{
   // treat value as integer ...
   int val = (int)myParam;
}
else if (myParam is String)
{
   string val = myParam.ToString();
}
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use generics. This will be helpful if you need to put constraints on the types that can be passed in:

```
public void BuildXml<T>(T obj)
{
    // do work
}
```

Or if you are expecting a collection of objects:

```
public void BuildXml<T>(IEnumerable<T> items)
{
    // do work
}
```

Then you can use reflection to get the relevant data you need.